# Want to Warn User of a Error by Making an Input Field Glow

Tags: jquery, validation, animation, input

Any way to do this in jQuery?

Doing some change event based validation of elements. When they tab or click out, I'd like to, if there was an error in the validation, to glow the input field a bit rid for a half second to let them know something was wrong.

Any way to do this easily in jQuery? I was thinking along the lines of animate() and a border property but this is a inputfield....

Comment: input fields have border property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the jQuery UI library, you can use the [highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) effect.

```
$("#Field").effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
```

Comment: @bobber, no problem. If this solves your problem, please don't forget to resolve your question by accepting an answer.

Comment: Done. You answered so quickly I had to wait 5 minutes. :D

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3UCbw/27/

You can use a wrapper div and apply some css3 styles.

```
div.highlight {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px red; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px red; 
    box-shadow:0 0 15px red; 
}
```

Comment: This works, but what are the initial black definitions for? The red seems to just override them.

Comment: @jocull - haha, nothing! It's been so long I don't remember. They don't do anything. I updated the fiddle, and answer.